# assigning a scalar the result of an SQL query

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

It seems to me that there simply has to be a better way of doing this, but i still haven't found one. And i'm sure i'm not the only one who could use a way to do this: Run an SQL query that only produces one field in one row, then assign that field to a scalar. (In my case, if the query results in more than one field/row, then i have bigger things to worry about than the script breaking).

For example, to get the timestamp from the SQL server, one could use:

```
my $timestamp;
my $cmd = $dbh->prepare('SELECT cast(now() AS timestamp);') or die $!;
$cmd->execute();
while (my @asd = $cmd->fetchrow_array) {  $timestamp = $asd[0] }
```

Dirty, but it works. But using 4 lines seem a bit much for a simple assignment, especially considering how well perl and postgresql can communicate with eachother via DBI. Sure, i could write a subroutine for it, but isn't there something native that allows me to fetch data as easily as i submit data with `$dbh->do()` ?

And yes, i did try google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually I write:

```
$value = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($sql)->[0]->[0];
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Also has the advantage of defaulting to the first row, if more than one is unexpectely returned.

Comment: Sorry, yes, i mean first. Edited accordingly, and now i'm getting my morning coffee.

Answer (score 1):

There's always [`selectrow_array`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#selectrow_array):

> *selectrow_array*
>
> ```
> @row_ary = $dbh->selectrow_array($statement);
> @row_ary = $dbh->selectrow_array($statement, \%attr);
> @row_ary = $dbh->selectrow_array($statement, \%attr, @bind_values);
> ```
>
> This utility method combines `prepare`, `execute` and `fetchrow_array` into a single call.

So something like this:

```
my $timestamp = $dbh->selectrow_array('select cast(now() as timestamp)');
```

There's also [`selectrow_arrayref`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#selectrow_arrayref) and [`selectrow_hashref`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#selectrow_hashref) for similar situations.

Answer (score 1):

From `perldoc DBI`:

```
   "selectrow_arrayref"

     $ary_ref = $dbh->selectrow_arrayref($statement);
     $ary_ref = $dbh->selectrow_arrayref($statement, \%attr);
     $ary_ref = $dbh->selectrow_arrayref($statement, \%attr, @bind_values);

   This utility method combines "prepare", "execute" and
   "fetchrow_arrayref" into a single call. It returns the first row of
   data from the statement.  The $statement parameter can be a previously
   prepared statement handle, in which case the "prepare" is skipped.

   If any method fails, and "RaiseError" is not set, "selectrow_array"
   will return undef.
```

That will get you most of the way.  You still need to do some error checking, but you would be doing that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't `fetchrow_array` actually only return a scalar as you're only asking for one column?

Comment: true, but it still would require a prepare/execute pair beforehand.